# Entity cutomization Publish details in MSCRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there any way to get the published history of entity in MSCRM 2011. Tab property of a form was changed and we need to track when changes was done and published and by whom. Solution will work in either way; by doing MSCRM SQL query or from CRM end.

Answer (score 3):

Bad news, I'm afraid: The only way to see a history of customization changes is if you regularly export, unpack, and check your customizations in to source control.